# Return Task with moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

### Issue

I have an issue where I want to unit test code that uses Task.WhenAll() at the end of the function. But I have no idea how to return an "uncompleted" task.

I want to return a Task<List> from a Mock (made with Moq). Does anyone know how that can be done?

I tried something like this:

```
_sourceServiceMock.Setup(s => s.ReturnA()).Returns(new Task<List<SourceOneDto>>)
```

### Code example

So I would like to return Task<List> from a service

How basically the thing I want to test looks like.

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o067w8)

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var sourceService = new SourceService();
        var a = sourceService.ReturnA();
        var b = sourceService.ReturnB();

        await Task.WhenAll(a, b);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Result[0].Data);
    }
}

public interface ISourceService
{
    Task<List<SourceOneDto>> ReturnA();
    Task<List<SourceTwoDto>> ReturnB();
}

public class SourceService : ISourceService
{
    public async Task<List<SourceOneDto>> ReturnA()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Task one done");
        return new List<SourceOneDto>{new()
        {Data = "data source one"}};
    }

    public async Task<List<SourceTwoDto>> ReturnB()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2);
        Console.WriteLine("Task two done");
        return new List<SourceTwoDto>();
    }
}

public class SourceOneDto
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class SourceTwoDto
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You mention moq in tags and title, yet show no moq code? Or is SourceService your mock?

Comment: why do you want an "uncompleted" task? Why not `Task.FromResult`?

Comment: @CodeCaster The sourceservice was meant to be what I want mocked. But yeah, I can add what I hoped would work.

Comment: So you want to test whether `Task.WhenAll()` waits until all tasks you pass complete? Or what is it you want to test exactly, and why do you think you need to pass it incomplete tasks?

Comment: @CodeCaster I want to test the data after it has been proccessed by WhenAll. I did not know I could pass it completed task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Liam and CodeCaster.

Seems like there is no need for incompleted `Task`s. Works fine with mocking up with `Task.FromResult();`

Something like

```
var sourceDto = new SourceOneDto {data: "one"};
_sourceServiceMock.Setup(s => s.ReturnA()).Returns(Task.FromResult(sourceDto));

//This might work as well
_sourceServiceMock.Setup(s => s.ReturnA()).ReturnsAsync(sourceDto);
```